# Transfering data from hard disk to external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have taken an back up of my system which is of 30GB, when i am transfering this back up file to an external hard drive , its showing up **"The file is too large for the destination file system"**.

Is there any method or software that i can use to transfer large files from my C: drive to external hard drive

Answer (score 2):

the problem is most likely the FAT32 file system (file size limit ~4GB) of the external HDD, convert the file system to NTFS.

**[How to convert a FAT16 volume or a FAT32 volume to an NTFS file system in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307881)**

*if the external HDD is empty, you might as well run a quick format using NTFS (much faster).*

Comment: He hasn't specified his operating system

Comment: "> He hasn't specified his operating system" but he asks if there's any method or software that he can use to transfer large files from his C: drive to external hard drive, Watson! :D

Comment: While the error itself is a Vista error, earlier windows versions did not have the convert tool, although they did have a C drive. You can also access your C drive on other operating systems, but I won't get into that here. I like challenging people, "watson".

Comment: My OS is windows Vista Home Premium Edition and meanwhile when i tried to check my external Hard drive its already in NTFS format

Comment: "While the error itself is a Vista error, earlier windows versions did not have the convert tool" i beg to differ, the 'convert tool' is available since Windows NT 4.0, the MSKB article refers to XP, which i think is earlier than Vista too :)

Comment: @bobby521: run "Check Disk" on the external hard drive.

Comment: @Molly I meant earlier versions of Windows in general, not all versions earlier than Vista. We really need to be able to edit earlier comments without deletion as it wrecks the reading order.

Comment: it does, doesn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a file splitter software: there are a few out there in the net. I'll suggest you one of those, that I had personally used, and that runs fine. [HJSPLIT](http://www.freebyte.com/hjsplit/). It is multiplatform and free: I used the Java version, but at the hjsplit site you'll also find some installer for Linux, Win 98/ME/XP, DOS, Amiga, etc...

Hope that helps,

Regards

Comment: Hope I think HJSPLIT does not support Windows Vista when i checked thier web site it did showed up vista support

Comment: use this link: is the java version of hjsplit: http://www.freebyte.com/download/hjsplit/hjsplit_g.jar, thus multiplatform