# Migrating data to hard-drive replacement (linux)

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, migration

My laptop hard drive was faulty so I requested and just received a new one. Now, I need to migrate my data over. This task seems easier said than done. The two drives are the same size, so I figure `dd` should work but I haven't seen explicit instructions on what exactly to do, and I'm scared for my data experimenting.

My setup is that these drives are **500gb** and internal so I can only have **one connected at a time**. About **250gb** on the hard drive is used. I have two partitions on the drive: a **boot** partition (50 megs), and a logical partition containing **root** (20gb), **swap** (8gb), **home** (435 gb). and reinstalling the operating system (gentoo) is not an option due to the fact that my bandwidth is severely limited right now. The only vehicle I have is an external USB hard drive with about **400gb** capacity. I'm currently booted off of an **ubuntu** livecd in order to do the transfer.

- Should I use dd to just copy the input drive into a file on the external HD? Or will this also try to allocate all the free space and thus not fit?
- Will zipping everything a la `dd if=/dev/sda bs=100M | gzip -c > /media/ext/image.img` fix that issue?
- Should I use dd to copy the /boot and / partition to a file on the external HD, and just copy my /home directory as files?
- Will either of these options leave me in trouble with booting and/or grub or something on the new drive?

Thanks!
Mala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I'd take the `dd` approach. **Back up your data first** onto that external of yours.

> - Should I use dd to just copy the input drive into a file on the
>     external HD? Or will this also try to
>     allocate all the free space and thus
>     not fit?

No. You can backup your drive as a regular imaged file, or even pipe to `dd` to gzip and back it up as a regular file. This way you save space:

```
dd bs=1024 if=/dev/sda conv=noerror,sync | gzip -9 > /mnt/usb/backup.dmg.gz
```

of course, replacing the drives appropriately.

> - Should I use dd to copy the / partition to a file on the external
>     HD, and just copy my /home directory
>     as files?

It depends. If you have a lot of custom configurations you don't want to lose, I'd just back up the whole thing. If not then your method would suffice.

> - Will either of these options leave me in trouble with booting and/or grub
>     or something on the new drive?

If the drives are identical, and you use `dd` correctly, and plug the new drive in just like the other, you should be golden.

Comment: *sigh* I can't both back up the data and do the migration for lack of space :-\. So I'll have to wing it and hope for the best. Thanks for the command, I'm trying it now

Comment: so just so I got everything right, once that command's done, I take out the old HD, put in the new one, and what command do I run to restore everything?

Comment: Hopyfully with gzip it will compress it a fair bit so you can fit both. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: While on a LiveCD, you can use `gzip -dc /mnt/usb/backup.dmg.gz | dd of=/dev/hd#`. Ensure both drives are mounted to those locations, replace `#` with the drive letter of the empty drive you're restoring to (eg, hda,hdb).

Comment: Yes. It will continue on read errors. If you'd like a much stricter dd, check out DDRescue ( http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue ). It will retry on error. It is available in Ubuntu and on bootable CD ( http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page ).

Comment: The command failed with "gzip: stdout: File too large" after 4gb...

Comment: You're probably trying to backup to a FAT formatted external drive, which is limited to ~4GB filesize. You'll need to convert it to another Filesystem. See this question ( http://superuser.com/questions/85881/transfering-data-from-hard-disk-to-external-hard-drive ). DDRescue is actually probably better for you if you're worried about whats happening behind the scenes. It has **very detailed progress** output as shown here: http://linux.softpedia.com/screenshots/GNU-ddrescue_1.jpg

Comment: I can't format the drive as it has data on it that isn't mine, so I have to use a smaller (150gb) drive. I figure my best bet with this is to just do /boot and /, and worry about /home later - I'll have to reinstall grub though, because this won't get my MBR, right?

Comment: You don't have to format it. If you have Windows lying around you can convert it to NTFS from the command line `convert G: /FS:NTFS` for example. dd will get your MBR and partition table.

Comment: sadly I can't do that. So now i'm doing 'ddrescue /dev/sda6 /media/ext/root.img' and 'ddrescue /dev/sda1 /media/ext/boot.img' after which I'll replace the drive, create the partitions and ddrescue the contents into them, reinstall grub, then start moving my /home across. Does this present any obvious flaws, or is there an obviously better way of going about this?

Comment: The images won't fit on the external. It must be converted.

Comment: ok I went out and bought another external drive - now my question is can I do all this skipping things like the swap partition, etc?

Comment: You can but it makes things more complicated. You need to do partitions separately then or seek to the barriers of the swap file and stop.

Answer (score 1):

use **[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)** to backup the 500 GB drive to the external HDD (if only 250 GB are used, then it's no problem to fit the image onto the 400 GB drive).

fit the replacement drive into the laptop and use Clonezilla again to restore the image to the new drive.

Comment: The page says, under Limitations, "* The destination partition must be equal or larger than the source one." I think this means it would not work for me?

Comment: no, this only refers to cloning, but not imaging. you can choose from the following compression options: Gzip, Bzip2, LZO. and when you restore the image, it will be a disk of the same size (equal), right?

Comment: yes, they're both 500gb drives from the same manufacturer. Do you know if Clonezilla can split its image file into pieces so that they'll fit on a FAT32 partition?